# Is there an index of all Micro Four-Thirds lenses?

Tags: lens, micro-four-thirds, search

I am looking for lens options for a new M4/3 camera I just bought. I'm particularly interested in landscape lenses. However when searching for lenses I can't find one place that has a complete index of M4/3 lenses. Is there such a place?

So far I've found this page with partial listings:

Limited to Panasonic, Olympus, Sigma, Cosina, Tokina
http://www.four-thirds.org/en/microft/lense.html

Lens here also doesn't appear to have all lenses in its search catalog.

Suggestions? (Or corrections.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our very own [Itai](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1620/itai) runs [Neocamera](http://www.neocamera.com/), which has such a [list](http://www.neocamera.com/list_lenses.php?mount=m43).

Comment: He doesn't have Voitlander or Tokina (even though there is only one, and it's a 300mm mirror lens). Maybe because they are manual lenses?

Answer (score 5):

The most comprehensive listing of Micro Four-thirds lens I am aware of is at this posting on the Micro 4/3rds Photography blog: http://m43photo.blogspot.com/2010/01/micro-four-thirds-lens-lineup.html.  Despite the misleading dateline from when this blog post was originally published, the post is regularly updated as new lenses become available.

Comment: I've updated this answer, as the information at the link is up-to-date (at least as of 2014-01-19) with all the latest lenses I am aware of from µ4/3 member companies and other compatible 3rd party lens vendors.  The dateline on the post is misleading.

Comment: This is particularly helpful because it not just a list but also provides a description and commentary for each lens.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a lens search on dpreview.com for current micro four-thirds lenses finds 52 lenses
[here](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/lenses?utm_campaign=internal-link&utm_source=mainmenu&utm_medium=text&ref=mainmenu#criterias=SpecsCoreParams&includeDiscontinued=No&sort=newestFirst&view=list&page=1&paramSpecsCoreParamsLensType=PrimeWideangle,PrimeNormal,PrimeTelephoto,ZoomWideangle,ZoomNormal,ZoomTelephoto,Superzoom&paramSpecsCoreParamsLensMount=MicroFourThirds&paramSpecsCoreParamsSubcriteria=LensMount,LensType,AdditionalFeatures&paramSpecsCoreParamsSearchType=Simple)

Answer (score 1):

The following list seems complete to me. All the Samyang, Voigtlanders, SLR Magic, and even a Schneider macro lens is listed, as well as rumored and announced but not-yet-released lenses (like the m.Zuiko 300/4). :)  Found via [this mu-43.com forum thread](http://www.mu-43.com/showthread.php?t=24679).

http://hazeghi.org/mft-lenses.html